# The background colour of a grouped UITableView will not go transparent in iOS7

Tags: uitableview, transparency, ios7, xcode5

I am working on an app, which worked perfectly fine with iOS 6. With iOS7 the app has couple of layout and general few appearance issues. One is not being able to set the background color of a grouped tableview to transparent. Heres is my code which does not work anymore

```
    tableForDetails = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, yAxisTable, 320, 150) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    UIColor *backGroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    UIView *bview = [[UIView alloc]init];
    [bview setBackgroundColor:backGroundColor];
    [tableForDetails setBackgroundView:bview];
```

Help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set background transparency for a grouped uiTableview in iOS7 is really quite easy. The solution is even more simple than I originally thought.

```
[tableForDetails setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

or for only semi transparent

```
[tableForDetails setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor alloc]initWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:0.5]];
```

This worked fine for me.

Comment: IMHO size is not the key requirement. This will work as well

    UIView* bgv = [[UIView alloc] init];bgv.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 [self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
 [self.tableView setBackgroundView:bgv]; The key seems to be setBackgroundColor

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I realise you are right. I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with this:

```
tableView.backgroundView = UIView.new;
```

Answer (score 0):

I put any kind of improvements on Apple components in a super class. The following upgrades are applied in BasicTableView.m, which extends `UITableView`:

1) overrides `setBackgroundColor` to work with iOS 7 and above, while maintaining backward compatibility with iOS 6 and 5.
2) overrides `initWithCoder:` and `initWithFrame:style:` to initialize the background color to a default transparent background

```
- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:decoder];
    if (self) {
        [self setup];
    }

    return self;
}

- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame style:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame style:style];

    if (self) {
         [self setup];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void) setup
{
    //Set the BG color to clear color by default
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
}

- (void) setBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)backgroundColor
{
    if (self.style == UITableViewStyleGrouped) {
        if (majorSystemVersion() < 7) {
            UIView *tableBgView = [[UIView alloc] init];
            tableBgView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
            self.backgroundView = tableBgView;
        } else {
            [super setBackgroundColor:backgroundColor];
        }

    }
}

//majorSystemVersion() is defined elsewhere in a utility file
int majorSystemVersion(void) {
    NSString *systemVersion = [UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion;
    NSArray *systemVersionComps = [systemVersion componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    NSString *majorVersion = [systemVersionComps objectAtIndex:0];

    return [majorVersion intValue];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

UITableViewCell is in white Background by default in iOS 7

put this inside your cellforRowAtIndexPath

[cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]]